# Make a fixed position element not pass a certain threshold on screen

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed position div:

```
<div id="fixed"></div>

#fixed {
  width: 300px;
  height: 375px;
  float: right;
  margin: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
}
```

Once I scroll to the bottom of the page I have a footer that has a height of 210px. And once I scroll to the bottom of the page my fixed div overlaps onto the footer. How can i make it so that the fixed div does not scroll over the footer?

Comment: Coud you please provide more HTML code? Try `overflow:auto;`

Comment: What do you want to happen to the header when you get down to the footer? Should it disappear/jump back to top?

Comment: Theoretically, the solution would be fix the footer to the lower of the viewport or the HTML so you can't scroll past it.

Comment: @arcyqwerty how can i make that happen? is there a css element for not allowing anything to scroll past it?

Comment: @ogk I think you need JS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  `javascript` is possible the see the snippet  if not then you can:

```
#fixed{
z-index: 2;
}    

your_footer{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

So at least it won't overlap the footer but go under it

**Note**  the `- 75` are the `75px` of margin you  have set and its best if you see the snippet full screen

```js
$(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var foff = $('footer').position().top;
    var fh =  $('#fixed').height();
    var h = $('#fixed').offset().top + fh;       
        
    if ( h >= foff) {          
        $('#fixed').css({
           position: "absolute",
           top: foff - fh - 75 
        });
    }else{
      $('#fixed').css('position','fixed');
    }
  });


});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#fixed {
  width: 300px;
  height: 375px;  
  margin: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  background: red;  
}
#content {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: 15vw;
  background: lightgrey;
}
footer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 290px;
  background: navy;
  position: relative;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fixed"></div>

<div id="content"></div>

<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```